# Debugging uboot

Tags: u-boot

While debugging uboot the step sequence are not continuous.
when i do next(n) at gdb prompt it goes to some other unexpected line.
I am doing a NFS mount on the target and debugging.
Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because normally the U-Boot binary produced by GCC has been optimized for size(to consume less storage space). You can build the U-Boot binary without optimization for easier debugging. Take a look at the Makefile of U-Boot and remove any optimization flags.
Information on optimization flags can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Step debugging also does not work pretty well with the macros and inline functions as the code is not actually placed where these are defined.

Answer (score 1):

@microMolvi's answer is right, you can `vim Makefile` on top directory of the uboot source, and find `CFLAGS` replace `-O2` (it's O not 0) by `-O0`, then it's ok to step by step.

By the way, maybe using s(step) in GDB is better.